# C# Azure Policy Recording Bot - starting out

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, call-recording

Okay, I'm trying to develop a Call Recording bot for the company I work for, to automatically join all incoming and outgoing Teams calls. It needs to record every call, save that call (probably on Azure), and create a database row containing pertinent information about that call (time started, time ended, phone #s involved in the call, a reference to the recording, etc.)

Now, I'm pretty much brand new to C# development (I have eight years of PHP development), so I'm starting with the Github repo that has the PolicyRecordingBot sample from Microsoft.

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/a3943bafd73ce0df780c0e1ac3428e3de13a101f/Samples/BetaSamples/LocalMediaSamples/ComplianceRecordingBot

I guess what I need to ask first is, even though this code doesn't actually record anything, does it automatically join Teams calls/detect audio? Or do I need to write the equivalent of an index.html page for the bot to trigger something in the CallHandler.cs class to "jump start" it?

Comment: open an issue in the same repo https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/issues to get help from the MS graph peeps.

Comment: i agree with @ranusharao. Try filing the issue in the above Github repro